# Printing to a modal window and not the browser in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am calling a function inside a modal window.
The function is printing out information using '.append'.
Problem is when the modal window is invoked, the function is run and 
prints in the browser window as well.   I am thinking it is the .append.
Can I run a function in the modal window to print in the modal window only.
Anyway advice is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use a print media

```
@media print {
  .modal {
    display: none;
  }
}
```